# Disable copy/paste of images in TinyMCE 3

Tags: javascript, tinymce, copy-paste

On an internal tool using TinyMCE 3.4.9, I'm asked to disable the possibility to paste images in the editor. (Images specifically; I do not want to disable copy-paste entirely: users should still be able to paste rich text or HTML content.)

I'm already using the `paste_preprocess` function to successfully detect when someone is pasting HTML code which contains `<img>` tags, and remove them:

```
paste_preprocess : function (pl, o) {
    if (o.content.indexOf('<img ') > -1) {
        o.content = o.content.replace(/<img[^>"']*((("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))[^"'>]*)*>/g,"");
    }
},
```

This works when the user copies images **on web pages** and pastes them in the editor.

However this does **not** work when the user copies an image **from their OS file manager** (e.g. Windows Desktop: select a JPG file, Ctrl+C, then Ctrl+V in TinyMCE).

In such a case, when I try to inspect the "o" object in `paste_preprocess`, the `content` property appears empty. Or to be more precise, it appears to contain the string `\ufeff\ufeff` which I think is related to Unicode encoding (?).

This allows me to write the following condition in `paste_preprocess`:

```
if (o.content == "\ufeff\ufeff") {
    console.log('image?');
}
```

I don't know if it's very pretty, but this appears to work. The `console.log` message is triggered when I paste an image from the OS, and not when I paste other types of content (HTML content copied from web pages, raw text from a text editor (Sublime Text) or rich text from a word processor (Libre Office)).

However, I don't know how to prevent the image to be pasted in the editor:

- if I do `o.content = ''`, the image is still pasted;
- if I do `o.content = "image"`, then the image is still pasted, with the text "image" right before it;
- if I simply do `return` or `return false`, the image is still pasted;
- `o.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `o.stopPropagation()` or `o.preventDefault()` all trigger a JavaScript error ("not a function").

I did the same with the `paste_postprocess` function, with the same results.

Disabling the `paste` plug-in in TinyMCE does not seem to change a thing.

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

Even if my entire `paste_preprocess` function is:

```
paste_preprocess : function (pl, o) {
    o.content = '';
},
paste_postprocess : function (pl, o) {
    o.content = '';
},
```

Then copy-pasting **text** is effectively disabled, but copy-pasting an **image** still works...